# Facebook like notifications with node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, socket.io

I kept searching for a tutorial that explains the logic behind facebook notifications (or any similar notifications system) and I couldn't really find any that approach this.
I mean those notifications with a dropdown that say "X commented on your picture" and so on.
How would you guys build such a feature with node? (socket.io?) What would you store in the database? If someone can give me some references would be great.

Answer (score -1):

I never did a notification system to be honest, but as far as I know, yes, sockets (and for node specifically, socket.io, it's the only one I know) can allow you to do that easily, you should look at their basic [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/) to learn more about it and understand how it can be done, and yes you can at the same time as notifying the user about the like, store it in a database for further reference, you can store the time, the profile who liked the post, the ID of the post, this kind of things.

Hope I'm clear and that you will find socket.io documentation easy enough to build your notification system!